# Stratified Random Sampling

Tags: sample-size, sample

I have a made up scenario that involves sampling from a factory that makes foot-long hot dogs. The 3 teams that make the hot dogs are graded on their ability to make foot-long hot dogs.  A previous 100% quality control study found that the teams' accuracy is around 90%.  The owner of the factory does not want to do 100% inspection.  For the first three days of Feb, samples sizes from each team were drawn using random sampling, 95% confidence level, 5% margin of error and 90% accuracy prediction.

Is there anything wrong with this method of sampling?

[image]